# Not Able to Get Custom Post Type in Single and Single-custom-post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development

I have a custom post type called `projectsCPT` and I am able to display them on `page-projectsCPT.php`

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Projects
*/
 get_header(); 
?>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:35px;">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'projectsCPT', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'  );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
$projectName = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_name', true); 
echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
  echo '<div class="panel-heading">'.$projectName.'</div>';
  echo '<div class="panel-body">';
    the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive', 'href' =>$thumb_url));
  echo '</div>';
 echo '  <div class="panel-footer"><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" role="button">More Details</a></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
    ?>        
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

but the

```
"<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" role="button">More Details</a>
```

is redirecting to `404.php` page!

I have a `single.php` and `single-projectsCPT.php` which I have repeated same code as `page-projectsCPT.php` to see if it is working but still getting to `404.php`

Comment: Is the url generated properly? Have you resaved your permalinks?

Comment: Hi Luis this is the URL `http://domain.ca/projectscpt/project-1/` can you please let me know how to reseraved the permalinks

Comment: In your wp-admin go to Setting > Permalinks then hit the save button. This will flush your permalinks.